# What does the symbol `?` mean in the expression `maxY = (maxY > pt.Y) ? maxY : pt.Y;`

Tags: c#

What does the symbol `?` mean in the following code:

```
  for(int i = 0 ; i < Hpts.BranchCount;i++)
    { foreach(Point3d pr in Hpts.Branches[i]){
        minX = (minX > pt.X) ? pt.X : minX;
        minY = (minY > pt.Y) ? pt.Y : minX;
        maxX = (maxX > pt.X) ? maxX : pt.X;
        maxY = (maxY > pt.Y) ? maxY : pt.Y;
      }
    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is called `conditional operator`.See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

> The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional operator.
>
> ```
> condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
> ```
>
> The condition must evaluate to **true** or **false**. If condition is true, first_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. If condition is false, second_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. Only one of the two expressions is evaluated.

So in your case for example:

```
minX = (minX > pt.X) ? pt.X : minX;
```

- `minX > pt.X` is **condition**
- `pt.X` is **first_expression**
- `minX` is **second_expression**

Which means that if condition is **true** value of `minX` will be equal to `pt.X`, otherwise it doesn't change because second expression is variable itself.

Answer (score 4):

This is equivalent to:

```
if (minX > pt.X)
{
    minX = pt.X;
}
else
{
    minX = minX;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

?: is a shorthand for if statement.
So here: minX = (minX > pt.X) ? pt.X : minX, minX will be set to pt.X if minX is larger than pt.X

Answer (score 3):

The conditional operator, so instead of writing this:

```
if (minX > pt.X)
    minX = pt.X;
else
    minX = minX;
```

You can write it like this:

```
minX = (minX > pt.X) ? pt.X : minX;
```

Answer (score 3):

The question mark (?), along with the colon (:) together form the **ternary conditional expression**. It is supported by most languages (I know C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Ruby all do that... feel free to correct me about the exceptions), and has the following syntax:

```
(condition) ? (code if true) : (code if false)
```

It is called **ternary** as it accepts 3 arguments, as shown above.

So to make a more concrete example, let's use the first line of your `foreach` loop to demonstrate

```
minX = (minX > pt.X) ? pt.X : minX;
```

This is equivalent to writing

```
if (minX > pt.X) {
  minX = pt.X;
} else {
  minX = minX;
}
```

As you can see, the 4 lines of code can be reduced into a single line without the loss of clarity, which is quite a powerful language construct. You will usually see this used quite heavily in recursive functions, e.g. function for calculating factorials:

```
int factorial(int n) {
  return (n == 1) ? 1 : factorial(n-1) * n
}
```